# Navigation bar with UIImage Button and subtitle

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to recreate something like the below image which is navigation bar with UIImage buttons and subtitle.

[image]
My current code looks something like in below

```
UIImage * cropModeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"crop"];
    UIButton *cropModeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [cropModeButton setImage:[cropModeImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cropModeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(_setCropMode:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UILabel *subtitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 20, 185, 30)];
    [subtitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [subtitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]];
    subtitle.text=@"This is the sub";
    [subtitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [cropModeButton  addSubview:subtitle];
    [self.view addSubview:cropModeButton];
    UIBarButtonItem *cropMode = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:cropModeButton];
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: I just want to make sure is this navigation bar or the tabbar?

Comment: Navigation bar.

Comment: No, that's not not a navigation bar.

Comment: That's a navbar that I created in android. I need to implement same for iOS

Answer (score -1):

In iOS, this is done using tabbar controller which generally appears at the bottom of the screen and if you want to show on the top of your screen then use the toolbar.

Look at the [calendar app of iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/navigation-bars/), it has 3 buttons to the right side and that's how it will look if you add buttons in the navigation bar.

I would prefer using the storyboard OR XIB for this and add all the barbutton items there and assign IBAction methods to it, [here's an example of how you can use storyboard for the same](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/04/14/adding-buttons-to-the-navigation-bar-with-storyboards/).

The buttons used in the toolbar can have images with captions to display the same look and feel.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want the button with subtitle/text/caption below it.

Comment: I am not really sure why the -1 really I would appreciate if there was some explanation for that.

Comment: @goops17 You can use an image for the button which has the color and title to get this done.